# Horror movie in a desert town where people start to kill each other and there was a nearby destroyed radar dish station

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, alien-invasion

I must have either watched it on Netflix or Shudder. Some main things I remember seeing was a satellite dish that gets destroyed, a dog that got sick, and some surviving teens had to hide out on a small cafe roof. There was also a scene where a girl who works with children at a school finds out one of the possessed/mind controlled citizens kills someone in the girls bathroom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was it that you watched this?

Comment: "Nightmare at Noon" hits a few points, but it's an adult couple that are the main focus. Are the teens the primary characters?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the Australian film [The DustWalker](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6816388/).

There are alien spores that turn people into zombie-like things, with a large scorpion looking alien kidnapping the infected. There is a large dust storm that keeps those in the infected area stuck.

Here is the best image I can find of the dish the scientist hang around.

[image]

> In a remote town in the Australian outback, a mysterious object crashes to Earth. When a human comes in contact with the object, that person becomes lifeless and deformed. These changed humans seem interested in the town's children and kill those remaining humans who stand in their way. The town's police officers, along with a schoolteacher and a scientist, all try to keep as many children safe as possible and understand what is happening to the town.
> —Timothy Gartin

From my recollection your points match the film, though I can't find much to support that and honestly not trying to rewatch to confirm.